# How to add coverflowView on ListActivity?

Tags: android

I have tried to the following code,which working fine to the Activity class,but i need to extends ListActivity class, but this code gives exception. 
    This class extends ListActivity

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(this .getResources()
            .getIdentifier("statusText", "id",
                    "com.customcoverflowproject.customcoverflowapplication"));
    // note resources below are taken using getIdentifier to allow importing
    // this library as library.
    final CoverFlow coverFlow1 = (CoverFlow) findViewById(this 
            .getResources().getIdentifier("coverflow", "id",
                    "com.customcoverflowproject.customcoverflowapplication"));
    setupCoverFlow(coverFlow1, false);
 "CoverFlow is another class which inherit to Gallery".
```

Comment: put your Exception log cat also

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
final CoverFlow coverFlow1 = new CoverFlow(this); 
relativeWWParam=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
relativeFWParam=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

relativeFFParam=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
relativeWWParam.setMargins(-((width/2)+(width/10)), 0, 0, 0);
getListView().setLayoutParams(relativeWWParam);
```